# Oracle Package Errors

Tags: plsql

I am running a jrxml file that calls an oracle package and am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: 
ORA-06550: line 1, column 14: PLS-00302: component 'EXAMPLE_PACK' must be declared 
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
```

This package however, has grant of Execute and debug.

```
GRANT EXECUTE,DEBUG ON EXAMPLE_PACK TO USER;
```

Edit

Spec ----

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tbaadm.fin_atmgl_pack
AS
   PROCEDURE fin_atmgl_proc (inp_str       IN     VARCHAR2,
                             out_retcode      OUT NUMBER,
                             out_rec          OUT VARCHAR2);
END fin_atmgl_pack;
/
```

Comment: Does EXAMPLE_PACK have a public synonym? Otherwise you would have to put the scheme name in front of it like SCHEME.EXAMPLE_PACK

Comment: Hi Joseph. To get a better responses, you should probably tag your question better. Some tags come to my mind  - [tag:plsql] and [tag:jasper-reports], but I am not sure, so edit your tags as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you @Piro.

Comment: Show us the code snippet of both spec and body.

Comment: Spec ----CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TBAADM.FIN_ATMGL_PACK AS
    PROCEDURE FIN_ATMGL_PROC ( inp_str IN VARCHAR2,
                out_retCode OUT NUMBER,
                out_rec OUT VARCHAR2);
END FIN_ATMGL_PACK;
/

Comment: @Joseph Without proper code snippet, it would be very difficult to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i am thinking 
**EXAMPLE_PACK** might be declared in ***package body*** but not declared ***package spec***.

Comment: Example_pack has SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_PACK declared on both the spec and body of the package. It also has it's grant to public. yet i still get the same error anytime i run it from my frontend